# Do I need voltage regulator?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, avr

I power my board with 5V and I am working with ATMEGA8, so I don't need to reduce the voltage. Do I still need voltage regulator for stabilization?  And if I do, would this work?

I used here 5V regulator and I saw this scheme in datasheet. As I understood, first capacitor is for noise reduce and the other is regular bypass capacitor.

I am using USB cable. So do i need any stabilizator there? Is there a chance if i connect this to power source it will burn the source?

On ADC pins i have connected IR sensors.

[image: olta]

Comment: What exactly will be connected to CON1? What will be the minimum voltage and maximum voltage connected at this point?

Comment: If the input voltage is 5v, you cannot use the 7805 as it requires more voltage than that.  It is hard to know if you need regulation, you haven't provided any information on your voltage source.

Comment: It depends upon the load's behaviour and the amount and rate of change of the current it draws. Here, the CPU draws a pretty narrow range of load current so what you've loaded up its output pins with and what else you've got on that rail are the big unknown factors. Please edit your question and expand it greatly, adding such details.

Comment: @cerouno, again, please edit and greatly improve your question - adding lots of info. Edit any new info into your question, don't post it as comments otherwise readers have to piece it together. If you look for a quick answer to a quick question, you get rubbish answers. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: How long is the power supply wire? You might need a small capacitor, maybe 4.7 μF (adjust as necessary), to counteract the inductive effect of a long supply wire if "my board" varies the current it takes.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using USB cable. So do i need any stabilizator there?

USB is reasonably well regulated, and your load isn't very sensitive to minor changes in voltage, so you don't need a regulator.

> Is there a chance if i connect this to power source it will burn the source?

That depends on the specific device, but most USB source or host devices have internal overcurrent protection.  If you are concerned that you might inadvertently short something, double check that your supply has protection or add a fuse.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using USB, so you won't need any voltage regulator. Mobile phone adapter or laptops provide a constant 5 volts. Use a good adapter and cable.

And 7805 has nothing to do in a circuit where the power is supplied from a 5 volts adapter. 7805 works for supply voltage greater than 7 volts.

Use a Schottky diode for reverse voltage protection.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you are connecting to CON1.

If it is fixed 5V, then you can't (and don't need to) use a 7805. Usually 7805 needs at least 7 V at its input to deliver 5 V.

If CON1 has more than 6 V, you should use a 7805. The output of 7805 will be 4 V with 6 V input, but ATMEGA8 can usually comfortably run down to 3.6 V. It will be 5 V for any voltage at CON1 greater than 7 V up to 45 V.

Comment: The 7805 regulation and output voltage is not guaranteed to be stable when operating with a below-spec input voltage. Even though the ATmega8 can operate from a lower voltage than 5 V, this lower voltage would come from a regulator with uncertain operation. A modern LDO regulator can be used within its spec' instead of an ancient 7805. Downvoting for these reasons, I'm afraid.

Comment: I am using USB cable. So you think i don't need any stabilizator there?

Comment: If you are using USB cable at CON1, then you don't need 7805 here. Just place a 10 uF and a 0.1 uF capacitor in parallel at the ATMEGA8 end of the USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a USB cable I assume you'll be using a 5V USB power source so there is no need to add a voltage regulator.

The only gotcha would be if you use the microcontroller's ADC and use the power supply as voltage reference, as the accuracy of the ADC would depend on the accuracy of the 5V power supply. This only applies if you use the ADC to measure a voltage that does not depend on the power supply itself. If you use it to measure the output of, say, a potentiometer or resistor divider, or anything else that has an output which is proportional to the supply voltage, then the ADC will give a correct reading even if your supply voltage is inaccurate.

Comment: Good catch of the ADC problem with unstable power supply. I would prefer the microcontroller's internal reference for the ADC in this situation.